# Phonegap-Xcode4-AppDelegate

Tags: xcode4, cordova

ok, so I am running this phone gap app in Xcode4. It finally runs fine in an iPad simulator. I was even able to make it work in a real iPad device. Then after couple of times downloading the code from Xcode to iPad, it started giving me this error:

int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");

The app just gets stuck there. I am new to this and really need help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be having an issue with the linked Phonegap files. Try doing a clean and then a run build.

Unfortunately, when the app fails on the Main line it doesn't help to debug the error any. Check the console and try hitting the continue button to see if it throws a better error.

Comment: I saw no luck. When I hit continue, the first time it stays on the same line and then when I hit it again it just exits. I am having a tough time figuring this one out.  Can you think of any potential reasons why it might fail on the main line.

Comment: Actually I didn't look hard enough I am getting this error:
Couldn't register "my application" with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code. This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.
I am trying to restart the iPad and see if that works.

Comment: Thats usually the fix. If restarting the iPad doesn't fix it try restarting your computer too. I have seen that before with PhoneGap projects.

Comment: actually just restarting the iPad helped me fix the problem.